# unbound prefix error on imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I made an imageview to include in other layouts and I am getting this error. "Error parsing XML: unbound prefix". Here's the code.

```
     <ImageView android:id="@+id/water" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/water"
                android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the android prefix:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:id="@+id/water" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/water"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```